# Как кастомизировать widget nav menu при разработке темы wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

Делаю тему wordpress использую underscores и bootstrap.

Я знаю что можно просто вставить меню в sidebar.php до вывода виджетов

Но я хочу выводить меню как виджет.

Я поясню,

Что есть сейчас:

```
<section id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
  <h2 class="widget-title">Menu title</h2>
  <div class="menu-top-container">
    <ul id="menu-top" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-30">
        <a href="http://#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31">
        <a href="http://#">Акции</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32">
        <a href="http://#">Кабинет</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Я хочу добавить классы бутстрап:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Когда мне понадобилось кастомизировать форму поиска я просто создал файл searchform.php и он заменил стандартную форму.

Какое есть решение в данном случае?

Comment: у вас два вопроса в одном ? 1) про меню 2) по форму поиска  - это так?

Comment: 1) Сейчас у меня проблема конкретно с меню. 2) с формой поиска я разобрался.